# how to add item in right click context menu of file and folder in objective c

Tags: cocoa, contextmenu, right-click, finder

I am developing an cocoa application for Mac and what i need is to add an item in the context menu that appears when user right-clicks on specific file and folder (i.e. when user click on file or folder by pressing ctrl key of keyboard).
I am new to Cocoa application development. I have searched in google for it and found that it can be implemented by using CFPlugIn. Does anyone know how to use CFPlugIn to implement this or any other method to add item in context menu of specific file or folder??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use system services for contextual menu. you should refer [Services Implementation Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MenuList/Articles/DisplayContextMenu.html). take a look at [Services step out in Snow Leopard](http://www.macworld.com/article/142419/2009/08/snowleopardservices.html) article.
If you wish to sell your product on apple app store than you should not follow dropbox.

Comment: I can't use Services as I have to show right click context menu on files in particular folder but if I use Services to show right click context menu then it will show it on all folders and files in finder.

Answer (score 0):

This is no longer supported in Mac OS X 10.6 and Mac OS X 10.7. Earlier versions of Mac OS X had support for contextual menu plugins, but this feature has since been removed.

What is it you're trying to accomplish in the broader sense? If you give us an idea of what your goal is, we may be able to suggest an alternate way to accomplish it.

Comment: Actually I need to add option in context menu when user right-clicks on file or folder as shown by Dropbox when we right click on a file or folder in Dropbox folder.

Comment: Dropbox does it by attaching hooks to the Finder. This is a bad thing and you should not try to replicate it. What's your broader goal?

Comment: As I told you, I want to implement functionality of right click same as Dropbox. So please tell me any alternative method to do this.

Comment: Yes, but to what end? What are you doing? Are you cloning Dropbox? What does your app actually do?

Comment: Actually I'm not exactly cloning Dropbox. It works like Dropbox. I will assign a folder to my Application and when user right clicks on any file in that folder then it will show option to upload that file in its context menu.

Comment: Hack into the Finder process and add a menu unsafely. Seriously, there's no API for this anymore.

Comment: On Mac OS 10.11, it still seems to be supported. Is this answer relevant?

Answer (score -1):

Using System Extensions and a FinderSync extension you can accomplish this.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Finder.html